# App get crashed in Core data but unable to find where it crashed

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am creating an IOS app including CoreData with Objective c. I am getting some core data error but unable to find on which line I am getting that error.

The error is showing in Firebase

> CoreData
>   -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _processRecentChanges:]

[image: Core data crash]

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
  EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x00000007fe226a10
 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _processRecentChanges:]
```

Comment: https://imgur.com/oGjcyu5 add the break point and check where it getting crashing

Answer (score 0):

EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS crash occurs when you try to access a deallocated object. Tracking with proper breakpoints might help.